# size and objdump report different sizes for the text segment

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I have tried this, but stuck up to the answer below questions where `hello_world-1.c` is

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The executed commands:

```
[kishore@localhost-localdomain ~]$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -c hello_world-1.c
[kishore@localhost-localdomain ~]$ gcc -o hello_world-1 hello_world-1.o
[kishore@localhost-localdomain ~]$ size hello_world-1 hello_world-1.o

    text    data    bss     dec    hex    filename
    1222     280      4    1506    5e2    hello_world-1
     139       0      0     139     8b    hello_world-1.o

[kishore@localhost-localdomain ~]$ objdump -h hello_world-1.o

    hello_world-1.o:     file format elf32-i386

    Sections:
    Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
      0 .text         0000003b  00000000  00000000  00000034  2**0
                      CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
      1 .data         00000000  00000000  00000000  0000006f  2**0
                      CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
      2 .bss          00000000  00000000  00000000  0000006f  2**0
                      ALLOC
      3 .rodata       0000000c  00000000  00000000  0000006f  2**0
                      CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
      4 .comment      0000002d  00000000  00000000  0000007b  2**0
                      CONTENTS, READONLY
      5 .note.GNU-stack 00000000  00000000  00000000  000000a8  2**0
                      CONTENTS, READONLY
      6 .eh_frame     00000044  00000000  00000000  000000a8  2**2
                      CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, DATA
```

Can anyone please help me to figure out what might be the reasons for the questions below?

1. The `size` command didn't list a stack or heap segment for `hello_world` or `hello_world.o`. What might be the reason behind this?
   (for above question, the answer is as I didn't called any function and also not used any heap segment, that's why they didn't showed up here. Am I correct?)
2. There are **no global variables** in `hello_world-1.c`. Why `size` reports that the **data** and **bss** segments have **zero length** for the **object file** but **non-zero length** for the **executable**?
3. `size` and `objdump` report **different** sizes for the **text segment**. Can you please advise  where the discrepancy comes from?

I have tried but failed to conclude on above 3 questions. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: You have no global *variables*, but you do have global data: an array of 13 `char`s corresponding to your string literal.  Plus anything that may be declared in `stdio.h`.

Comment: For #3: does `size -A hello_world-1.o` display a text segment size closer to what `objdump` displays?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1) Heap and stack are created by the OS at run time; that is, after the executable has been loaded into virtual memory. Therefore, they are not part of the executable file.

2) Because the executable also contains data -- and code, mind you -- from the `stdio` library that has been linked to the object file by the linker.

3) Because `size`, invoked like this (without any parameters) displays sizes according to the Berkeley convention. Under this scenario, the `text` entry reports the combined sizes of three different segments:

`.text`

`.rodata`

`.eh_frame`

On the other hand, `objdump` reports the size of `.text` only. You can see the sizes of `.text`, `.rodata`, and `.eh_frame` separately with `size` if you invoke it according to the SysV convention, like this: `size -A hello_world-1.c`.  Then you will see exactly the same info you see with `objdump`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

For Question #2.
It is because there are few default global variables defined when the linking is done to create a executable. Below command can show the symbol table. Two variables each of 4 bytes are __data_start and __bss_start.

objdump -x  hello_world-1

**0000000000601030 g       .data  0000000000000000              __data_start**

**0000000000601034 g       .bss   0000000000000000              __bss_start**

For question #1
Stack and Heap will not be mentioned in the executable because they are dynamically allocated by the OS. The binary file only provides sections that are static in nature. Like, contents and sizes of data, text & bss segments are fixed at compilation time.

For Question #3
Check the source of size util at
https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=binutils/size.c;h=dcfd9547b25cdd58db890f9fe0dc9a3ba9228d89;hb=HEAD#l449.

It displays addition of all ReadOnly/Code sections as text. i.e

```
 446 static void
 447 berkeley_sum (bfd *abfd ATTRIBUTE_UNUSED, sec_ptr sec,
 448               void *ignore ATTRIBUTE_UNUSED)
 449 {
 450   flagword flags;
 451   bfd_size_type size;
 452 
 453   flags = bfd_get_section_flags (abfd, sec);
 454   if ((flags & SEC_ALLOC) == 0)
 455     return;
 456 
 457   size = bfd_get_section_size (sec);
 458   if ((flags & SEC_CODE) != 0 || (flags & SEC_READONLY) != 0)
 459     textsize += size;
 460   else if ((flags & SEC_HAS_CONTENTS) != 0)
 461     datasize += size;
 462   else
 463     bsssize += size;
 464 }
```

So if you take the output of objdump and add all readonly/code sections then you will get value 1222